# Changing RAM in Laptop

Tags: memory, upgrade, dell-vostro

I have a Dell Vostro 2520. I am planning to upgrade the amount of RAM to 6GB.

My laptop has a Core i3-2328 processor and is currently running Windows 7 ultimate , but after the RAM upgrade, I plan to go to Windows 8.

When I upgrade the RAM in my laptop, can I use a 2GB module and a 4GB module?

Comment: It really helps if you tell us what processor and OS you have. Examples of nearly useless information include "i3" and "win 7". Examples of useful information include "Windows 7 Professional, 64-bit" and "Core i3 3120-M".

Comment: Please go edit your original question and update it instead of posting another one about the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [dell manual](ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_vostro_notebook/vostro-2520_Owner%27s%20Manual_en-us.pdf) this laptop takes either 1 or 2 SODIMM memory modules, in each slot with a maximum of 4gb in each slot. SODIMM's can act either as single channel (each slot independently) or dual channel (two same sized memory sticks in each slot).
So the bios should accept a 6GB configuration running in single channel mode. The 2520 manual doesn't list each individual combination type, but most other dell manuals do.

More important to consider is your OS choice. A 32 bit version of Win7 or Win8 will only see/use 3GB of addressable memory. So be sure to get the 64bit version of Win8. If you already have the 32bit version, then just upgrade to the 2gb memory.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your question but here:http://www.crucial.com/store/listparts.aspx?mfr=Dell&model=Vostro%202520 it says that you can use x2 4gb together and that your laptop has two slots, so I think you CAN insert a 2gb and a 4gb ram together.